# iOS 16 lock screen new wallpaper > Photo Shuffle > People: How to add additional people?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app, wallpaper

When adding a new wallpaper in the the new iOS 16 lock screen customization, in the Photo Shuffle option, one of the options is People.

In that section, on my iPhone running iOS 16, I'm only offered a choice of 2 people: Myself, and a single one of my children.

However, in the Photos app, in the Search screen, in the People section, all of the members of my immediate family are listed (with a correct photo); including my spouse, and all 3 of my children, among a few others.

How do I get the iOS 16 lock screen wallpaper Photo Shuffle option to include *all* of the people that my iPhone knows about, instead of just a couple of them?

Comment: I believe you need a minimum number or quality photos of the people. Mine shows ~15 people but I have many more in my library.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than letting iOS' (proprietary, somewhat poorly understood) image processor decide for you, just create an album, the set that in your customized Lock Screen.

From the Photos app, choose Albums, then tap the + icon to create a new album.  Select your preferred photos then tap Add.

Then from the Lock Screen, press and hold to access the new Customize feature.  Tap the + icon to add a new  wallpaper; tap Photo Shuffle, then Select Photos Manually, then Albums. From inside your new album, select the images you'd like displayed.  Finally, click Add and confirm the wallpaper/homescreen options.

Comment: how does this help to solve the problem asked in the question?